# Pow.cx with xip.io Rails app still uses .dev for CSS & JS assets

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I've successfully accessed a local Rails app, setup using pow.cx, via a mobile device and Edge Inspect using xip.io. Great. Only problem, all my CSS & JS assets still use the .dev domain, rather than the xip.io domain, so the pages appear completely un-styled, with no javascript.